# simple json parsing to create new list

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to JS, and this is the json I get.
I need to fish out all the answers by their order and get the index of the right one.

any references?

```
 //what i got
    var questions = 
    {"Q_id":1, "Q_question":"why yellow minions?", 
    "Q_correctFB":"Very good!",
    "Q_notCorrectFB":"try again...",
    "Q_skill":"disney",
    "Q_answers_lst": [
        {"A_id":1, "Q_id":1, "answer":"too much bananas!","isCorrect":1},
        {"A_id":2, "Q_id":1, "answer":"all minions are cowards","isCorrect":0},
        {"A_id":3, "Q_id":1, "answer":"liver problems","isCorrect":0}
    ]
    };
```

And I only need a list of all possible answers, which is this:

```
//what i need

var ans_lst = ["too much bananas!", "all minions are cowards", "liver problems"]
```

I know I should start with:

```
var lst = questions.Q_answers_lst;
```

but then how to clean the tagged data?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `reduce` to archive this

```js
var questions = 
    {"Q_id":1, "Q_question":"why yellow minions?", 
    "Q_correctFB":"Very good!",
    "Q_notCorrectFB":"try again...",
    "Q_skill":"disney",
    "Q_answers_lst": [
        {"A_id":1, "Q_id":1, "answer":"to much bananas!","isCorrect":1},
        {"A_id":2, "Q_id":1, "answer":"all minions are cowards","isCorrect":0},
        {"A_id":3, "Q_id":1, "answer":"liver problems","isCorrect":0}
    ]
    };

var answers = questions.Q_answers_lst.reduce(function (acc, value) {
  return acc.concat(value.answer);
}, []);
console.log(answers);
```